# Extract excel data to text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file whose data is from left to right. I want to copy it in a notepad from top to bottom. Let me explain. As shown in the [excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRfQH.png), the excel sheet is divided into layers, Layer 0, Layer 1 and so on.
[image]
I want the vba code to copy all the data from the first column (Layer 0) up until the 5th column  into notepad. Then start copying the data again from the 6th column (layer 1, the red boundary) up until the end of that layer on a new line. The operation goes on and on. So that it produces a result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yBcy.png). This is what I tried
[image]

```
Sub SaveAsTxtFile()
Dim FileName As String
Dim SLine As String
Dim Deliminator As String
Dim Lastcol, LastRow, FileNumber As Integer
'Locationand File Name
FileName = "/Users/random/Desktop/G_code.Path.txt"

Deliminator = " "
Lastcol = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FileNumber = FreeFile

'creating or Overwritting a text file
Open FileName For Output As FileNumber

'Reading the datafrom the excel
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To Lastcol
        If j = Lastcol Then
            SLine = SLine & Cells(i, j).Value
        Else
            SLine = SLine & Cells(i, j).Value & Deliminator
        End If
    Next j
    'Writing data in test file
    Print #FileNumber, SLine
    SLine = ""
Next i
Close #FileNumber
MsgBox "Text file has been generated"

End Sub
```

But the result of this reads from left to right instead of top to bottom in the notepad like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmibe.png).
I think the key is to detect if there is a keyword "LAYER" in a cell, if this is so, then it knows it should start printing to the next line (under the previous ones) in notepad.
[image]

Comment: If you know that the layers are only 5 columns wide then your loop through the columns should do that in sets of 5.  So you need three loops: `For i = 1 To LastRow` `For j = 1 To Lastcol Step 5` and `For k = j To j+5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub ExportSheetsToTxt()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myString As String
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
        'FileName = CurDir & "\" & Ws.Name & ".txt"
        FileName = "/Users/random/Desktop/G_code.Path.txt"
        With Ws
            r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            For i = 1 To c Step 6
                Set rngDB = .Cells(5, i).Resize(r - 4, 6)
                myString = myString & getString(rngDB)
            Next i
     End With
     TransToTxt Filename, myString
    MsgBox ("Files Saved Successfully")
End Sub
Function getString(rng As Range)
    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim strTxt As String
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR)
    Next i
    strTxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    getString = strTxt
End Function
Sub TransToTxt(myfile As String, strTxt As String)
    Dim objStream As Object
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strTxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. I got a syntax error which was on this line. `TransToTxt xcsvFile, myString` . I figured you had to mean this `TransToTxt FileName, myString`. Then It worked and I got another error on this line inside the TransToTxt function `.WriteText strTxt`. Please understand, I am no good with vba, I just had to use it for a task.

Comment: @awwal, sorry mistype, i edited. `TransToTxt xcsvFile, myString`  mistyped. to `TransToTxt Filename, myString` is corret.

Comment: @awwal, I can't know exactly how your data is actually done. The assumptions in my example are written on the premise that your data continues in the column direction from row 5.

Comment: I understand. What about this `.SaveToFile myfile, 2` I get a syntax error on it. I think the argument `SavetoFile` is meant to be something slightly different

Comment: @awwal, Check to see if your text file is already open.
2 is to overwrite an existing file if it exists, and to create a file if not.